# Context menu not showing up in Microsoft Edge extension

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm trying to add a context menu item to a Microsoft Edge browser extension, but it is not showing up at all.

I am using the Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 14372

I have looked at the documentation for [supported apis](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/supported-apis/) which says that the contextMenus API are supported in the Edge browser.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Sample Context Menu",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "description": "Adds a context menu item when you select some text",
  "author": "author_name",

  "icons": { 
    "16": "icon/icon16.png",
    "32": "icon/icon32.png",
    "48": "icon/icon48.png",
    "128": "icon/icon128.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["index.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

index.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "sample",
    title: "Sample Context Menu",
    contexts: ['selection']
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == "sample") {
        var selected_text = info.selectionText;
        console.log(selected_text);
    }
});
```

I'm getting  **Script5007: Unable to get property 'create' of undefined or null reference** error message when I look at the Developer Console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `browser.*` instead of `chrome.*`.

Comment: @Ishan, glad to help.